# Android how can play song for 30 seconds only in mediaPlayer

Tags: android

I am working on Android , I am creating a player for audio songs. I want to play a song only for just 30 seconds. After that, player must be closed. It should be start again, if I press `START` button again.

This is the code for creating a media player:

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    public void songPreview(String songURL){

        try{
        mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songURL);
             mediaPlayer.prepare();
             mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me what code should I use to play my song only for 30 seconds after that it will stop, and if I want to play again then I have to press start button.

Note: Please provide me logic to stop media player after 30 second.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use countdownTimer to complete your goal in which you can set countdown timer till 30 second manually. when countdown finish process it will go to finish method and execute finish method code
::

```
    CountDownTimer cntr_aCounter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            mp_xmPlayer2.start();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //code fire after finish
               mp_xmPlayer2.stop();
        }
        };cntr_aCounter.start();
```

Comment: you welcome. i have also working project where some time limitation i play audio automatically i have lots of searching on it and finally i have found this timer.

Comment: Please accept answers that work best for you. It helps keep our community successful.

Comment: In this example, onTick() would be called every second. It doesn't have an effect though since MediaPlayer.start() executes only once.

Comment: Your example works fine, I'm just saying that a CountDownTimer is a bit of an overkill since onTick() would be called every second. You can achieve the same with a Handler, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

```
private void playSoundForXSeconds(final Uri soundUri, int seconds) {
    if(soundUri!=null) {
        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(Settings.this, soundUri);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               try {
                   mp.stop();
               }catch(Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }, seconds * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I much prefer this suggestion because Java is not .net, you don't need to get things to work, you need to work hard to get things smart. Especially on android and other mobile platforms that doing 'nasty' stuff will incearse battrary life and slow down the phon.

Answer (score 1):

This method jumps to the end of the track after a given time and allows the native onCompleted callback do its work. You'd obviously need to expand the code to handle any pause events fired before the playback completes.

```
    private static void startMedia(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, @Nullable Integer previewDuration) {
    mediaPlayer.start();

    if( previewDuration != null) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            }
        }, previewDuration);
    }
}
```