# Seting the duration of Media Player media in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I want to set the time duration for `MediaPlayer`. Here is my code:

```
MediaPlayer play = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.beepsound);
play.start();
```

Comment: Is...this all you've got?

Comment: Try this [Android how can play song for 30 seconds only in mediaPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383808/android-how-can-play-song-for-30-seconds-only-in-mediaplayer)

Comment: i want set duration for 1 sec how to define that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` which will be updated every 1000 milliseconds. Then set time to a `TextView` or what ever you want.

```
if (player != null) {
    player.start();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
                        tv.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tv.setText(player.getCurrentPosition());
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```