# How to set Media player Duration in android

Tags: android

i want to play MediaPlayer for 1 second. How to set Duration in this code..

```
    player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beepsound);
    player.start();

    CountDownTimer Timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            player.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            player.stop();
        }
    };
    Timer.start();
```

Comment: You just posted this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052851/seting-the-duration-of-media-player-media-in-android) sometime ago. Is this a coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything on the `onTick` method.

Try this code:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beepsound);
player.start();

CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       // Nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
             player.stop();
             player.release();
        }
    }
};
timer.start();
```

If you look at the constructor:

```
public CountDownTimer (long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
```

`millisInFuture` - The number of millis in the future from the call to start() until the countdown is done and onFinish() is called.
So `onFinish()` will be called after 1 second (1000 millisecond = 1second).

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long, long)

Comment: See my updated answer. And don't forget to remove player.start(); from your onTick() method.

Comment: thank for your valueable information, but when i am setting 5000 millisecond for duration it is not working..

Comment: ok one more question is there, now i want to play Media Player after 10 seconds.

Comment: Since this is a new query, you should post it as a new question.

Comment: I have posted as new question Mr. Ali ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061371/i-want-to-play-media-player-after-10-seconds

Answer (score 3):

You could use TimerTask to schedule a MediaPlayer.stop() to run after 1 secs.

```
TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaPlayer.stop()
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000); //execute in every 20000 ms
     }
```

can u try this one

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}, timeout);
```