# I want to play Media Player after 10 seconds

Tags: android

I want to play media player after 10 seconds time delay in android.

player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sleep);
        player.start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is with Handler

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  public void run(){
    player.start();
  }
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like below: The trick is to start the player after 10 seconds by using a `CountDownTimer`

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beepsound);

CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {                       
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        player.start();
    }
};
timer.start();
```

Don't forget to stop & release the player when done with it.